# makefile erro " *** No target specified and no makefile found.stop."

Tags: makefile, mingw

I have a makefile that contains this code

```
all: hello.exe

hello.exe: hello.o
     gcc -o hello.exe hello.o

hello.o: hello.c
     gcc -c hello.c

clean:
     rm hello.o hello.exe
```

When i write this command

```
  mingh32-make
```

I got this:

```
  mingw32-make : *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.
```

Comment: Is your makefile named `Makefile` or `makefile`?  Is it in the same directory where you're running `mingw32-make`?

Comment: My makefile name is makefile and it is also in the same directory where i am running mingw32-make

Comment: That can't be right.  Are you sure you don't have some kind of extension on the makefile name?  If you type `dir makefile` does it show you info on the makefile?  Or does it say "file not found"?  Then if you run `mingw32-make` right afterwards without changing directories you get this error?  Be sure none of the characters in the name `makefile` are special characters that just look more or less the same.

Comment: Extension of makefile is .txt and on typing dir makefile it says that File Not Found

Comment: Afterwards i getting the same error as previous.

Comment: Well, that's your problem.  When I say the makefile needs to be named `makefile` I mean exactly that: `makefile`, not `makefile.txt` (or any other extension).  Rename the file to be just `makefile`, with no extension, so that when you type `dir makefile` you see the file (and not "file not found") and you'll be all set.

Comment: I save the make rule into a file named Makefile.txt and hello.c program & Makefile.txt are in the same directory.And i also typing the command mingw32-make from this directory where hello.c and Makefile.txt resides.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable information.After removing extension everything working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this in 2 ways.

1. As the commenters say, rename your file from `makefile.txt` to `makefile`.
2. Another way, use `mingw32-make -f makefile.txt`